Storybook not taking the styles
I was trying to build a single storybook for shadcnui, mantineui and parkui,
started with matineui, it works fine for me but when i try to configure shadcnui,  the styles not taking by storybook, How do i solve this

main.ts
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-vite";

import { join, dirname } from "path";

/**
 * This function is used to resolve the absolute path of a package.
 * It is needed in projects that use Yarn PnP or are set up within a monorepo.
 */
function getAbsolutePath(value: string): any {
  return dirname(require.resolve(join(value, "package.json")));
}
const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: [
    "../packages/**/src/stories/*.mdx",
    "../packages/**/src/stories/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)",
  ],
  addons: [
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-onboarding"),
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-links"),
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-essentials"),
    getAbsolutePath("@chromatic-com/storybook"),
    getAbsolutePath("@storybook/addon-interactions"),
  ],
  framework: {
    name: getAbsolutePath("@storybook/react-vite"),
    options: {},
  },
  
};
export default config;

preview.tsx
import React from "react";
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import { MantineProvider, createTheme } from "@mantine/core";
import { ThemeProvider } from "../packages/shadcnui/src/index";
import "@mantine/core/styles.css";
import "../packages/shadcnui/src/styles/global.css";

const theme = createTheme({
  fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif",
  primaryColor: "blue",
});

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
  },
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <MantineProvider theme={theme}>
        <ThemeProvider>
          <Story />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </MantineProvider>
    ),
  ],
};

export default preview;

Created a theme component inside packages/shadcnui/src/components
ThemeProvider.tsx
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";
import { cn } from "../lib/utils";


interface ThemeProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

// Example ThemeProvider Component
export const ThemeProvider: React.FC<ThemeProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className={cn("min-h-screen bg-background font-sans antialiased")}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

tailwind configured
packages/shadcnui/tailwind.config.js
const { fontFamily } = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme")

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  darkMode: ["class"],
  content: [
    './packages/shadcnui/src/**/*.{html,js,ts,tsx,jsx}',
    './.storybook/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    './packages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',  
  ],
  theme: {
    container: {
        center: 'true',
        padding: '2rem',
        screens: {
            '2xl': '1400px'
        }
    },
    extend: {
        colors: {
            border: 'hsl(var(--border))',
            input: 'hsl(var(--input))',
            ring: 'hsl(var(--ring))',
            background: 'hsl(var(--background))',
            foreground: 'hsl(var(--foreground))',
            primary: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--primary))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--primary-foreground))'
            },
            secondary: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--secondary))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))'
            },
            destructive: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--destructive))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))'
            },
            muted: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--muted))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--muted-foreground))'
            },
            accent: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--accent))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--accent-foreground))'
            },
            popover: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--popover))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--popover-foreground))'
            },
            card: {
                DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--card))',
                foreground: 'hsl(var(--card-foreground))'
            }
        },
        borderRadius: {
            lg: '`var(--radius)`',
            md: '`calc(var(--radius) - 2px)`',
            sm: 'calc(var(--radius) - 4px)'
        },
        fontFamily: {
            sans: ["var(--font-sans)", ...fontFamily.sans]
        },
        keyframes: {
            'accordion-down': {
                from: {
                    height: '0'
                },
                to: {
                    height: 'var(--radix-accordion-content-height)'
                }
            },
            'accordion-up': {
                from: {
                    height: 'var(--radix-accordion-content-height)'
                },
                to: {
                    height: '0'
                }
            }
        },
        animation: {
            'accordion-down': 'accordion-down 0.2s ease-out',
            'accordion-up': 'accordion-up 0.2s ease-out'
        }
    }
  },
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss-animate")],
}
         

packages/shadcnui/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "moduleResolution": "nodeNext"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "components", "src/lib"]
}

my story book

Please let me know what i am missing and how to solve the style not taking issue

Please have codeblocks instead of images. I am not going to copy all of it just to help you.

Sorry, i have updated, Thanks!!
